# Where is the Windows 8 mail settings option?

Tags: windows-8, email

I have installed Windows 8 Pro and I can't see the the account option [as suggested here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/web-apps-help/set-up-email-in-windows-8-mail-HA102834576.aspx)

in the charms --> Settings option, all I see is tiles and another 2 options.

How do I change the mail settings options?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to open the Mail App and then open `Charms -> Settings -> Accounts`

`Settings` displayed on the Charms menu change based on the app. So do actions for `Search, Share & Devices`. If you open the Charms menu on the start screen, you would see the Tiles and other options, as u mentioned.